# How to trim the result of speedtest-cli to only output the download speed?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'd like to periodically display my speedtest download speed result in [indicator-sysmonitor](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/ubuntu-appindicator-that-displays-bash.html).

speedtest-cli has a somewhat trimmed output if you run

```
$ speedtest-cli --simple
Ping: 50.808 ms
Download: 10.87 Mbit/s
Upload: 4.47 Mbit/s
```

Is there any way to trim the output even more, down to just the download speed numeral?

Comment: You can use  `--no-upload` option to don't display upload either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As `speedtest-cli` is a python program and library it's fairly easy to make a minimal alternative program that only performs a download test and prints the output.

Open an editor, save as `dl-speedtest.py`

```
import speedtest

s = speedtest.Speedtest()
s.get_config()
s.get_best_server()
speed_bps = s.download()
speed_mbps = round(speed_bps / 1000 / 1000, 1)
print(speed_mbps)
```

run with `python dl-speedtest.py`

This gives the result in <strike>bps, as a floating point number</strike> Mbps rounded to one decimal as requested

The minimal version of speedtest-cli for this to work is 1.0.0 I think, you may need to use `pip install speedtest-cli --upgrade` to upgrade.

Comment: Beauty, thanks! As great as @dessert's answer is, this is what I ended up using due to efficiency. I'm polling it every few minutes so trimming the fat on unnecessary calls is beneficial to me.

Comment: @Adam You should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/961827/edit) your question and change it accordingly then – the title doesn't match this answer currently.

Answer (score 12):

That's a job for `awk`:

```bsh
speedtest-cli --simple | awk 'NR==2{print$2}'      # just the numeral
speedtest-cli --simple | awk 'NR==2{print$2" "$3}' # numeral and unit
```

#### Explanations

- `NR==2` – take line `2`
- `{print$2}` – print the second column (space-separated by default)
- `{print$2" "$3}` – print the second column followed by a space and the third one

---

With `sed` it's a little more complicated:

```bsh
speedtest-cli --simple | sed '/D/!d;s/.* \(.*\) .*/\1/' # just the numeral
speedtest-cli --simple | sed '/D/!d;s/[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1/' # numeral and unit
```

#### Explanations

- `/D/!d` – search for lines containing `D` and don't (`!`) `d`elete them, but every other line
- `s/A/B/` – `s`ubstitute `A` with `B`
- `.*` – take everything
- `[^ ]*` – take everything that's not (`^`) a space
- `␣` (space character) – a literal space
- `\(…\)` - take everything inside and save it as a group
- `\1` – get the content of group 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
speedtest-cli --simple | grep "Download: " | sed "s/Download: //g"
```

Comment: Instead of `grep` combined with `sed`, you can simply use `sed -n` and append `p` at the end of the expression, like `speedtest-cli --simple | sed -nr 's/Download:\s*//p'`.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
speedtest-cli --simple | grep -E "Download:\s*" | sed -r 's/Download:\s*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

And then there's:

```
speedtest-cli --simple | grep Download | awk '{print $2}'
```

Like dessert's first option though without the line selector.

Comment: It's rarely useful to do `grep ... | awk` - `speedtest-cli --simple | awk '/Download/{print $2}'`